# Prestashop keeps redirecting to old domain

Tags: redirect, prestashop

I want to install a local replica of a Prestashop site, but when I enter local domain, it keeps redirecting me to old domain.

I downloaded files, downloaded and imported database, updated settings to point to local database, etc.

I updated `ps_configuration` table to set `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN` and `PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL` to new local domain and disable (set to 0) all cache parameters in this table.

I edited `.htaccess` so all references to old domain get changed by new domain, and deleted all cookies and cache in browser. In short, I have the exact same problem than [Prestashop redirects to old domain after changing it in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398176/prestashop-redirects-to-old-domain-after-changing-it-in-database) but its solution doesn't work to me. Also, I restarted Apache, and still the same. A curl or the local site shows this info:

```
curl -v example.me
* Rebuilt URL to: example.me/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to example.me (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: example.me
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 15:40:56 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< Vary: Host
< location: http://example.com/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.me left intact
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to update the `ps_shop_url` informations. There are two ways:

**From the backoffice**

Change your domain in `Preferences -> SEO & URL`.

**Directly into database**

– In **ps_configuration** change PS_SHOP_DOMAIN and PS_SHOP_DOMAIN_SSL to your new domain name, e.g. mydomain.com

– In **ps_shop_url** table change ‘domain’, ‘domain_ssl’ fields to your new domain name. Change ‘physical_uri’ to your folder path, if you copied files into root folder, the path will be simply ‘/’.

After that, remember to regenerate the .htaccess from the backoffice, `Preferences -> SEO & URL` as PrestaAlba sayd.

Comment: The virtualhost is configured to listen at `example.me`, that's what `domain` and `domain_ssl` have. BTW, I can't access panel, so I changed them directly in database

Answer (score 1):

Do what @sarcom said and after that delete your htaccess file, go to backoffice, disabled Friendly URL and that should be all.

Good luck.

Comment: Still the same problem. I can't access panel, I get PHP error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_file()`, maybe related?

Comment: Of course is related. Check your hosting PHP version. That function is from PHP 5 and PHP 7. Anyway this function should be used to download Prestashop updates notification, so if you can find the line you could comment on source code. Good luck.

Comment: I have PHP 7 in localhost, I can see this problem here, but this doesn't solve the redirection issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36407094/761076

Comment: You should do what @sarcom said. You could do it accessing backoffice in Preferences -> SEO & URL menu.

Comment: Phewww, done!, there seem to be a lot of issues with this prestashop version (1.5) and php 7, in fact my current task is upgrade version

Comment: @K.Weber I'm assuming host version doesn't use PHP 7, so you shouldn't be using it on your local machine (if you wanna develop and push updates on live). It can cause you massive headaches when stuff works on local but breaks on live.

Comment: And you mark initial answer as valid???? Remember me that in future before help you. Good luck.

Comment: Sorry about that, your answer says "do what @sarcom said" and it's the correct action, deleting htaccess or disabling friendly url didn't help, I voted up your answer and some of your comments, you are free to help or not, thanks a lot for your help, as your comments did help, but in order to help other people who read this, the correct action is the first answer

Comment: @TheDrot yes, server has an older php version, I will check compatibility problems with Prestashop 1.6 and that version of PHP

Answer (score 1):

### How to move PrestaShop 1.7.2.3 to another domain

### Changing the PrestaShop URL  1.7.2.3

### Migrating PrestaShop 1.7+

1. Firstly clear your cache. [short movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kOEOFjswpo)

   - Go to zzz.com/admin
   - choose **advanced parameters** from left menu
   - than choose **Performance**
   - click **Clear cache** in the top right corner
2. Create new domain on your server
3. Eksport your database to zzz.sql in phpMyAdmin
4. Open zzz.sql file, find and replace your domain e.q. zzz.com to ggg.com
5. navigate to old shop's path

   - cd home/zzz.com/public_html/
6. copy all files

   - cp -R public_html ../ggg.com
7. navigate to new shop's path

   - cd home/ggg.com/public_html
8. setup permissions for directories

   - sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} “;"
   - sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ";"
9. setup correct user owner for files *www-data*. Cause now it can be a root

   - go to public_html: cd home/ggg.com/public_html
   - chown -R www-data:www-data .
10. open to phpMyAdmin

    - create new db **ggg**
    - import **zzz.sql** file
11. Edit **database_name** variable directory from **zzz** to **ggg** in below files.

    - home/ggg.com/public_html/app/config/parameters.php
    - home/ggg.com/public_html/app/cache/dev/appParameters.php
    - home/ggg.com/public_html/app/cache/prod/appParameters.php
12. DONE!

Answer (score 0):

ps_shop_url (Change table prefix 'ps' to the one you have). Changing this corrected my Prestashop 1.6 version installation.